# SQL data model for selling houses

Tags: sql

Im designing an application for a realtor (estate agent) for selling houses, where property transaction refer to a "Seller" and a "Buyer" who both need to be registered as clients in the database.

I dont know how to link the sales table to the clients table where a "Sale" needs to reference both a buyer and a seller whom at the same time are both registered clients.

any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You use two columns in the sales table, one that holds the ID of the seller and the other the ID of the buyer.

Comment: both columns referencing the clients table?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

registering sellers in agent table and buyer in buyers table.then use foreign keys to establish relationships

```
create table client
(
    id    int primary key,
    name  varchar(255) not null,
    state char(4)      not null,
    city  varchar(255) not null
);

create table sales
(
    id        int primary key,
    buyer_id  int not null,
    saller_id int not null,
    amout     double(10, 2)
);

alter table sales
    add constraint foreign key (buyer_id) references client (id),
    add constraint foreign key (saller_id) references client (id);
```

Comment: Thank you.  The client can be both a seller or a buyer

Comment: so then you can create one client table and add clients to that table insted both agent and buyer tables and connect client table with sales table using client_id.`clint(id, name, etc..), sales(buyer_id, saler_id, etc..)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your database to have this format. I have made basic details based on your request.

Hope it helps.[image: design of database]